# Renderman 24 no valid licence when rendering in blender

Tags: rendering, renderman-render-engine

So I installed renderman 24 on blender and trying to render says I don't have a valid renderman licence.
It's probably because I'm using the github version but renderman installer doesn't install the program!
Anyone got any ideas on how to fix?

Comment: I'm not sure if your Q match's BSE guidelines ... Probably better to ask some Renderman community ? Or here are some instructions https://rmanwiki.pixar.com/display/RFB24/Installation+of+RenderMan+for+Blender

Comment: Hi Zach, welcome to the Blender stack exchange.  Are you talking about Renderman For Blender (https://github.com/prman-pixar/RenderManForBlender)?

Comment: Yes and I did everything right tho it's not rendering because of 'no valid licence'

Answer (score 1):

I instaled *RenderMan* for *Blender* like this, so here is a step by step guide of how I did it:

Hope this all helps you.

**Note that maybe your problem may be because of this:** *RenderMan*
only works on *Blender* 2.83 LTS or *Blender* 2.92.

1. Go to: https://renderman.pixar.com/store.

Then on the *Non-Commercial* section choose *Try*.
[image]

2. Then on the page you come to, click on the big *Free to Try* button.
   [image]

If you do not have an acount or you are not login, login or create an acount and then come back to the same page.
[image]

3. Then you will be prompt with form, fill it all an click *Submit*.
   [image]
4. After this you will come back to the page on step 2 but now with a download button after scroling click it!
   [image]
5. Then you it will open a sucsess page but just close it and run the program you just down loaded.

It will open a instalation wizard, istall it.
[image]

6. Then it will open a login window, login.

[image]

7. Now after all of this go to RenderMan's GitHub: https://github.com/prman-pixar/RenderManForBlender/releases

Scoll down a bit and download the RenderManForBlender-24.0_2172149.zip file
[image]

8. Now FINALY install that zip file in *Blender* as a addon.

Comment: I did do that but no rendering options work, pressing the render or render animation button comes up with the render tab, with a transparent background and hovering my mouse over says I don't have a valid licence. Trying the real-time render makes the percentage in the top-left of the view port say 66% done, and every object is grey/kinda transparent. I did install the newest version off github and the installer and non-commercial, signed up and everything. And I tried the 2.92 AND 2.83 LTS, using the steam version on a windows 10 laptop.

Comment: In GitHub did you download the latest version of code or latest release?

Comment: Now RenderMan 24.1 is out, you can try it and it will also work for 2.93